# Where did the NSLog go, when user download my Apps from App Store?

Tags: iphone, nslog

Can the Using enable to see the NSLog when they plug the device on their mac? or is this possible to see the NSLog from the user?

Answer (score 1):

Yep. You should do something like what's outlined by [Cocoa is My Girlfriend](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/01/24/dropping-nslog-in-release-builds/) to hide it from the users.

Comment: I have used this in every project.  Absolutely great code snippet.